# Adding fields to nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formbuilder

So I have a model called City and it `has_many :places` and it `accepts_nested_attributes_for :places`. Each Place `belongs_to :category`. When I render a form for a City I have `f.fields_for :places do |place|` and I do it like this:

```
<% f.fields_for :places do |place| %>
  <%= render "place_fields", :f => place
<% end %>
```

My _place_fields.html.erb contains the folowing:

```
<div class="place_header"><%= f.object.category.name %></div>
<div><%= f.label :name %>: <%=f.text_field :name %> </div>
<div><%= f.text_area :description %> </div>
```

But the problem apears when I try to add a new place. First of all I want to bring up a simple select form to select a category for the new place, and then render that same partial based on the category_id.
I do that inside the same action:

```
def add_place
  if params[:category_id]
    @place = Place.new(:category_id => params[:category_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { return nil }
      format.js {
        #here comes the render
      }
    end
  else
    render_message :header => "Choose category", :partial => "category_select", :over => 10
  end
end
```

But if I try to do `$("#places_tab").append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "place_fields", :f => @place %>");` it gives an error, wich is expected.

Once again: I need to render the fields for that new Place and just don't know how to do that.

**UPDATE**

Received some advice on passing the original City Formbuilder to the action and rendering that Place right from that builder, but don't have any idea of how to do that.

Comment: If it's expected, what's your question? What's the error message? Also, I don't see a div with `#places_tab` in your code.

Comment: The error is that there is no method label for a Place.
The question is how to solve that error, how to make a Formbuilder out of a Place record.
The #places_tab is a wrapper for the fields_for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing an instance of the Place model (@place) as the form builder instead of the form builder itself.

Comment: $("#places_tab").append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "place_fields", :f => @place %>"); Where is this in the view?  It could be as simple as removing the @.